# setting up a proxy to mirror an SSH SOCKS connection

Tags: ssh, proxy, transparent-proxy, socks

I have two remote machines, remote1 and remote2.  remote2 is only running sshd, and I can't run anything else on it.  remote1 is a full-fledged server to which I have complete access.  I can run a SOCKS proxy on remote2 via `ssh -f -N -D *:8080 me@remote2` which lets me expose a SOCKS proxy on port 8080 on remote1.  I'd like to authenticate this so that the proxy isn't sitting open.  How can I do this?

It seems like I should be able to use [delegate](http://delegate.org), but I can't even seem to get its HTTP proxy functionality working.  When I run `delegated -r -P8081 SERVER=http PERMIT="*:*:*" REMITTABLE="*"` I can't even get it to work on port 8081.

Anyway, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to let me authenticate access to the SOCKS proxy connection?  That is, I want to be able to point my browser's proxy at remote1 and browse the internet through the SSH SOCKS proxy/tunnel to remote2.

squid doesn't support a SOCKS parent =(

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

nylon supports SOCKS mirroring with ACL's

http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=nylon

Answer (score 0):

If you want remote1:8080 to be accessible only from some local network, change from "-D *:8080" to "-D $IP:8080", where $IP is local network address of remote1.

If you want `you <-(ssh)-> remote1 <-(ssh/socks)-> remote2 <-> internet`, you may do:

1. Change from "-D *:8080" to "-D 127.0.0.1:8080".
2. Always ssh from "you" to "remote1" with option "-L 127.0.0.1:8080:127.0.0.1:8080" and use 127.0.0.1:8080 as SOCKS proxy. It will be mapped to remote1:8080, then to remote2 and finally to internet.

You can also set up a pair of stunnels or socats that will protect your connection with SSL certificates.

Comment: I want `me <-(http/SOCKS proxy)-> remote1 <- (ssh/SOCKS) -> remote2 <-> internet` -- that is, I _only_ want to set up a proxy on my local machine (not have to `ssh`).  I was thinking I could maybe put the proxy behind some sort of http authentication?  I'm not familiar with stunnels or socats--can they do what I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. Provide a list of limitations for hosts "remote2", "remote1" and "you". Why can't you just ssh to "remote2" with "-D" option? What can you run on "you"? (ssh client? only browser? Third-party tools like socat/stunnel?) What can you run on "remote1"? Describe what is "you", "remote1" and "remote2".

Comment: I actually ended up getting this to work with [polipo](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~jch/software/polipo/).  I can only run a browser (with a proxy extension of some sort) on `you`.  I can run anything I want on `remote1` and I can only run `sshd` on remote2.  I was trying to set up an ad hoc proxy which lets me expose a network I only have ssh access to, but I didn't want to open up a totally unprotected proxy.

Comment: OK, with these limitations `polipo` should be right solution.